# python silenium

Tags: python, веб-программирование

Есть вот такая форма на сайте, при выборе файла предлагает выбрать файл с компьютера и при нажатии кнопки Импорт - загружает себе на сервер.
Вопрос, как с помощью sileniuma допустим, сделать так чтоб путь к файлу я смог вставить свой (не компа локально, а именно со стороннего сервера)

[image: python]

Comment: Вариант скачать удаленный файл во временный каталог и отдать ссылку на него я так понимаю не рассматривается?

Comment: удаленный файл по факту уже лежит на одном сервере. Silenium заходит на сторонний сайт с этого же сервера.... мб получится и ссылку передать

Comment: Кто мешает скачать файл на сервер(wget\ curl) и отдать путь до уже "локального", а не удаленного файла, я об этом

Comment: так сервера не локально находятся и доступа к первому нету